# ValueError: Mean Squared Logarithmic Error cannot be used when targets contain negative values

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

```
cross_val_score(estimator=LinearRegression(), X=X, y=y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_log_error', cv=5)
```

results in the following error:

```
ValueError: Mean Squared Logarithmic Error cannot be used when targets contain negative values.
```

even though my target vector has no negative values (house prices)

```
>>> np.any(y < 0)
False
```

I know the log function is undefined for negative values and that mean squared log error uses this formula: [image]

This means the problem must lie with y hat i.e. after fitting the linear regression predicts a negative value, but this isn't the case:

```
>>> np.any(LinearRegression().fit(X,y).predict(X) < 0)
False
```

I've read the answers to similar questions but I'm still not sure what's causing this error and how to fix it. This same error happens with other regularized linear regressors too such as Ridge, Lasso, ElasticNet when using cross-validation. However when I use

```
mean_squared_log_error(y, model.fit(X,y).predict(X))
```

with these same models i.e. to find the training score it works perfectly with no error.

My goal is to submit the predictions on Kaggle. They use root mean squared log error to evaluate the performance, but if my predictions are sometimes negative, how does kaggle churn out a score anyway using this metric?

when using cross-validation with other scorers such as neg_mean_squared_error

```
cross_val_score(estimator=LinearRegression(), X=X, y=y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5)
```

there is of course no problem, so can I use the cross val scores with this metric to evaluate the performance of my models i.e. will the models with the lowest neg_mean_squared_error also have the lowest neg_mean_squared_log_error?